# Searching for a proper way to reduce the dimensionality of activations from a CNN

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, dimensionality-reduction, computer-vision

I am conducting an analysis to compare the similarities between different images across early and late layers in a CNN. The model I am working with is the pretrained DenseNet121 that comes with pytorch. My procedures are like this:

1. Register forward hooks on features maps `transition1.norm`, `transition2.norm` and `transition3.norm`;
2. Use the registered model to identity a 400×400 image;
3. Take the activations from the registers and compute cosine similarities between images.

However, the activations are large in sizes after `Tensor.flatten()`. In my case, the size of `transition1.norm` is 2,560,000, the size of `transition2.norm` is 1,280,000, and the size of `transition3.norm` is 640,000.
These data devoured my disk space and slowed down my computation. I found actually a large part of the data are composed by
zeros. As shown below:

```
tensor([[[[0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
           0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
          [3.3772e-02, 3.3772e-02, 3.1638e-02,  ..., 3.1638e-02,
           3.1638e-02, 3.2013e-02],
          [3.3772e-02, 3.3772e-02, 3.1638e-02,  ..., 3.1638e-02,
           3.1638e-02, 3.2013e-02],
          ...,
          [3.3772e-02, 3.3772e-02, 3.1638e-02,  ..., 3.1638e-02,
           3.1638e-02, 3.2013e-02],
          [3.3772e-02, 3.3772e-02, 3.1638e-02,  ..., 3.1638e-02,
           3.1638e-02, 3.2013e-02],
          [6.6977e-01, 7.4104e-01, 7.4104e-01,  ..., 7.4104e-01,
           7.4104e-01, 7.4104e-01]],


           ... TRUNCATED ...

           
         [[4.4522e-01, 2.8640e-01, 2.7194e-01,  ..., 3.1157e-01,
           1.7369e-01, 6.2406e-02],
          [1.2590e-01, 2.1647e-02, 9.2064e-02,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
           0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
          [0.0000e+00, 1.8316e-02, 6.2189e-02,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
           0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
          ...,
          [0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 3.5624e-01,  ..., 9.1325e-02,
           6.8744e-02, 0.0000e+00],
          [0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00, 3.3750e-01,  ..., 0.0000e+00,
           0.0000e+00, 0.0000e+00],
          [8.0560e-02, 1.7131e-01, 4.5834e-01,  ..., 3.0711e-02,
           5.3941e-02, 1.1774e-01]]]], device='cuda:0')
```

My question is: except for simply removing the dimensions where 0 appears for every stimuli, what are the most efficient and reliable ways to reduce the dimensionality of the activations without losing or distorting information from the original activations?

Edit: To be clearer, I am not only asking about the methods to reduce dimensionality. The question is about whether there are standard procedures in deep learning to address liking questions, given that I only have experiences in statistics but not in deep learning and CNN etc.